# How to strip a value from a delimited string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, join

I have a list which i have joined using the following code:

```
patternCore = '|'.join(list(Broker['prime_broker_id']))

patternCore
'CITI|CS|DB|JPM|ML'
```

Not sure why i did it that way but I used patternCore to filter multiple strings at the same time. Please note that Broker is a dataFrame

```
Broker['prime_broker_id']
29    CITI
30      CS
31      DB
32     JPM
33      ML
Name: prime_broker_id, dtype: object
```

Now I am looking to strip one string. Say I would like to strip 'DB'. How can I do that please?

I tried this

```
patternCore.strip('DB')
'CITI|CS|DB|JPM|ML'
```

but nothing is stripped

Thank you

Comment: What type is `Broker`: is it a Pandas dataframe, a dictionary or something else?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: Strategy:  Remove it from the list (or prevent it from appearing in the list), then join.  (Also, even if [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) did what you think it does, it still wouldn't produce what you want:  "The `chars` argument is a string specifying the **_set_ of characters** to be removed." [emphasis added])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Broker` is a Pandas dataframe, you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with Boolean indexing, then use [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
mask = Broker['prime_broker_id'] != 'DB'
patternCore = '|'.join(Broker.loc[mask, Broker['prime_broker_id']].tolist())
```

A more generic solution, which works with objects other than Pandas dataframes, is to use a list comprehension with an `if` condition:

```
patternCore = '|'.join([x for x in Broker['prime_broker_id'] if x != 'DB'])
```

Without returning to your input series, using the same idea you can split and re-join:

```
patternCore = 'CITI|CS|DB|JPM|ML'
patternCore = '|'.join([x for x in patternCore.split('|') if x != 'DB'])
```

You should expect the last option to be expensive as your algorithm requires reading each character in your input string.

Comment: Thank you jpp for your answer it works fine but i was thinking whether we can do it without coming back to Broker['prime_broker_id']. Is there a way to strip patternCore?

Comment: Thank you jpp it is very helpful

Answer (score 3):

I would like to mention some points which have not been touched upon till now.

> I tried this
>
> `patternCore.strip('DB')`
>
> `'CITI|CS|DB|JPM|ML'`
>
> but nothing is stripped

The reason why it didn't work was because `strip()` returns a copy of the string with the **`leading` and `trailing` characters** removed.
NOTE:

1. Not the characters in the occuring somewhere in the mid.
2. > The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

Here you have specified the argument characters as 'DB'. So had your string been something like `'CITI|CS|JPM|ML|DB'`, your code would have worked partially(the pipe at the end would remain).

But anyways this is not a good practice. Because it would strip something like
`'DCITI|CS|JPM|MLB'` to `'CITI|CS|JPM|ML'` or `'CITI|CS|JPM|ML|BD'` to `'CITI|CS|JPM|ML|'` also.

> I would like to strip 'DB'.

For this part, @jpp has already given a fine answer.